# ThumbImage is not proper in UISlider

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiimage, uislider

I am using a UISlider in my application to show the download progress.I am facing a issue which is strange and occuring only in landscape mode.

Prob:

[image]

I could see a line behind the thumb image of UISlider which is a transparent glowish image.

below are the images:

[image: min Image] min Image

[image: Max Image]  Max Image

[image]

Below is the code:

```
 [downloadProgress setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"progess_bar_black_left.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [downloadProgress setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"progess_bar_black_right.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [downloadProgress setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glow.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have checked the frames of the UISlider and it is same in both Orientations.
It is surprising to know that the issue is occuring only in landscape mode.

Has anyone faced a issue similar to this.If so i please help me in sorting out the issue.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Is Autolayout enabled? Try turning it off, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @He Was I have checked and the frame size remains same in all orientations..